# Why does Firebase not recognize the current user after logging in?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

After logging out of the current user in Firebase using Auth.auth().signOut(), I run this to register a new user:

```
    guard let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text else {
        print("Form is not valid")
        return
    }

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (FIRUser, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error ?? "error")
        }
        print("Account creation successful")
    })


    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
        print("No UID")
        return
    }
```

However, it does not recognize any current user. However, if I run it a second time, in the same session, it will recognize the user. I tried setting a delay as well using Dispatch queue but that did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you restart the app, it may take some time before Firebase can verify that the user is still authenticated. Rather than blocking your app, it allows the app to continue and then fires a so-called "auth state change" event when it is done. To ensure you catch this event, you need to add a completion block as shown in [Get the currently signed-in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed_in_user):

```
handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much! I've implemented the listener and it is now working perfectly.